# OpenLayers 3 DragBox not displaying on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When I shift + drag on the map and release, the 'boxend' listener fires. Additionally, if I inspect the map object after adding the dragBox interaction to the map, the dragBox interaction is in the map object. The issue is that the box is never visible on the map while selecting a region. What am I missing?

```
 $scope.drawBox = () => {
    const dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
      condition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: [0, 0, 255, 1],
          width: 2
        })
      })
    });

    map.addInteraction(dragBox);

    dragBox.on("boxend", function(e) {
      console.log("boxend called"); // listener is triggered
    });
  };
```

Comment: Also, the coordinates for the dragBox extent are present in: dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of OpenLayers version v3.11.0 changed how you style ol.interaction.DragBox and ol.interaction.DragZoom. Rather than using a style attribute when creating the object, you have to style the feature with CSS.

Old:

```
 new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: [255, 255, 255, 0.4]
        })
      })
    })
```

New:

```
.ol-dragzoom {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

Comment: Did this work?  I tried this and still have no style for my dragBox?

Comment: Yes. It worked. I would check the version of OL you are using if you havent. I was using 3.11.0. Prior to that the style was in the ol.interaction rather than the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I use OL 3.14, and I solve the problem with that CSS:

```
.ol-dragbox {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color: rgba(100,150,0,1);
  }
```